# Order of the group of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of all $\ 2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ where $ad-bc\neq 0$ and $a,b,c,d$ are integers modulo $3$, relative to matrix multiplication. Show that $|G|=48$.

**My solution:** Since entries of the matrices are from $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{[0],\ [1], \ [2]\}$ and there are total $3^4=81$ matrices. Let's count the number of matrices, where $ad=bc\in \{[0], [1], [2]\}$
The number of each case is $25,\ 4,\ 4$, respectively. In total it will be $25+4+4=33$. So $|G|\leqslant 81-33=48$. But how to prove that $|G|$ is exactly $48$.

I'll try by contradiction: suppose that $|G|<48$ but my results were unsuccesful.

Please help with this.

Comment: You have your result: just use equal sign instead of $\leq$ sign.

Comment: @JeanMarie, why should I use the sigh $=$ instead of $\leqslant$? What if the order of group $G$ is strictly less that $48$?

Comment: There are $33$ matrices where $ad = bc$, so the other $48$ must fulfill $ad \neq bc$. As long as you can assume that $G$ is a group, you are thus done.

Comment: The only constraint you have on these $3^4=81$ matrices is that $ad \ne bc$. You have enumerated the number of cases(33) where you have $ad = bc$. Then the subtraction $81-33$ gives you the result...

Comment: @DirkLiebhold, But I can not understand that. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @JeanMarie, What if some matrix with $ad\neq bc$ does not lie in $G$?

Comment: @JeanMarie, You said above "As long as you can assume that $G$ is a group, you are thus done". Could you explain this, please?

Comment: Its Dirk that has said it.

Comment: @JeanMarie, could you answer my above question? about matrix which does not lie at $G$

Comment: This can not happen because you have done an exhaustive count.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have shown that $G\cup A=T$ where $G\cap A=\varnothing$ and $|A|=33, |T|=3^4=81$. Right?

Comment: That's it, plainly : you have made a partition of $G$.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no left time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $8$ possible ways to choose $(a,b)$ ($3 \times 3$ but we must avoid $(0,0)$). Now $(c,d)$ must be linearly independent of $(a,b)$ so there are $6$ ways to choose this pair. So $ \mid G \mid = 6 \times 8 = \color{blue}{48}$.

Comment: I have already done that. I have shown that $|G|\leqslant 48$. But I cannot comprehend why this bound is exact. That's my question

Comment: @RFZ No, I m sorry, you have not "done that". Donald Splutterwit just gave you a different proof.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that i have found that number 48. But i am asking again what if there is some matrix with $ad-bc\neq 0$ which does not lie in that $G$?

Comment: Nice proof and very nice method. But how to generalize your solution for $ad-bc=1$?

Comment: Consider the map 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b &   \\ c & d &  \\ \end{array} \right) \rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2a & 2b &   \\ c & d &  \\ \end{array} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
from this it is quite easy to see there is a one-one correspondence between matricies with $ad-bc=1$ and $ad-bc=2$.